# Serverless Framework Cloudwatch Events

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I am using serverless version 1.27.3

trying to get a cloudwatchEvent to link codebuild to a lambda as the state changes.

here is the function:

```
  sightbox-devops-codebuild-bot: 
    handler: src/slack/codebuild.default
    events: 
      - cloudwatchEvent:
          description: 'Cloudwatch Event triggered on codebuild build state change'
          event:
            source: 
              - 'aws.codebuild'
            detail-type:
              - 'CodeBuild Build State Change'
            detail:
              state:
                - FAILED 
                - IN_PROGRESS
                - STOPPED 
                - SUCCEEDED
          enabled: true
```

When I do `sls deploy`
The cloudwatch event never gets created.

Comment: did you figure this out?  working on same thing right now

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is easy.

If you have already deployed your serverless package you must first remove the stack and redeploy. then the event gets created.